# Fatal error in wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am new to this group. After I installed YOAST SEO plugin i'm getting this error message "Fatal error: Call to undefined function apply_filters_deprecated() in /home/ipzen/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/admin/menu/class-admin-menu.php on line 246" i cant find the plugin in cpanel as well. Help me solve this problem

Comment: What version of Wordpress are you using?

Comment: Sounds like an old version of the plugin.

Comment: `apply_filters_deprecated()` is only available in WordPress 4.6 or higher. Yoast SEO currently requires WordPress 4.8 or higher. You should update your site if it doesn't match that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Access your server via [FTP/ SFTP](http://codex.wordpress.org/FTP_Clients) , or a file manager in your hosting account’s control panel (consult your hosting provider’s documentation for specifics on these), navigate to /wp-content/plugins/ and delete wordpress-seo plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Plugin via FTP as metioned earlier in this thread. Install the newest WP-Version and reinstall the plugin. It should work !